# fail2ban nginx-badbots. Help to set proper regex

Tags: nginx, fail2ban

Have such access.log configuration

```
'$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
'$host $server_addr $request $status $body_bytes_sent '
'"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" '
'"$http_x_forwarded_for" $request_time '
'$upstream_response_time ' '$upstream_addr';
```

and a real output example

```
157.55.39.158 - - [20/Jul/2020:06:40:06 +0000] xxx.site xxx.siteIP GET /xxx/url HTTP/1.1 200 40006 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)" "-" 0.055 0.056 xxxUpstreamIP:xxxUpstreamPort
```

example of *nginx-badbots.conf*

```
badbots = bingbot|axios|Axios...and so on
badbotscustom = BotBot|Axios|axios...and so on
```

tried next failregex options:

```
#failregex = (?i)<HOST> -.*"(GET|POST|HEAD).*HTTP.*(?:%(badbots)s).*"$
failregex = ^<HOST> -.*"(GET|POST).*HTTP.*"(?:%(badbots)s|%(badbotscustom)s)"$
#failregex  = ^<HOST> .*(GET|POST|HEAD).*(%(badbots)s).*$
#failregex = ^<HOST> -.*"(GET|POST|HEAD).*HTTP.*(?:%(badbotscustom)s|%(badbots)s).*"$
#failregex = ^<HOST> -.*"(GET|POST|HEAD).\/.HTTP\/1\.1".(\d{3}).(\d{3}|\d{4})."-"."(?:%(badbots)s|%(badbotscustom)s)"$
```

but unfortunately nothing happens

example of fail2ban-regex output

```
[root@nginx filter.d]# sudo fail2ban-regex  /var/log/nginx/access.log /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/nginx-badbots.conf

Running tests
=============

Use   failregex filter file : nginx-badbots, basedir: /etc/fail2ban
Use         log file : /var/log/nginx_buyr_com/access.log
Use         encoding : UTF-8


Results
=======

Failregex: 0 total

Ignoreregex: 0 total

Date template hits:
|- [# of hits] date format
|  [50719] Day(?P<_sep>[-/])MON(?P=_sep)ExYear[ :]?24hour:Minute:Second(?:\.Microseconds)?(?: Zone offset)?
`-

Lines: 50719 lines, 0 ignored, 0 matched, 50719 missed
[processed in 12.42 sec]
```

How to build a proper regexp for badbots?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.*` before and after each of the user agent strings otherwise the regex wil not match as it tries to match that enitre string between the two quotes. I use the below, `.*apache.*` and everything after that is what i added to the pre-installed badbots filter:

```
    badbotscustom = EmailCollector|WebEMailExtrac|TrackBack/1\.02|sogou music spider|.*apache.*|.*java.*|.*hello.*|.*grab.*|.*wget.*|.*ZoominfoBot.*|.*python.*
badbots = Atomic_Email_Hunter/4\.0|atSpider/1\.0|autoemailspider|bwh3_user_agent|China Local Browse 2\.6|ContactBot/0\.2|ContentSmartz|DataCha0s/2\.0|DBrowse 1\.4b|DBrowse 1\.4d|Demo Bot DOT 16b|Demo Bot Z 16b|DSurf15a 01|DSurf15a 71|DSurf15a 81|DSurf15a VA|EBrowse 1\.4b|Educate Search VxB|EmailSiphon|EmailSpider|EmailWolf 1\.00|ESurf15a 15|ExtractorPro|Franklin Locator 1\.8|FSurf15a 01|Full Web Bot 0416B|Full Web Bot 0516B|Full Web Bot 2816B|Guestbook Auto Submitter|Industry Program 1\.0\.x|ISC Systems iRc Search 2\.1|IUPUI Research Bot v 1\.9a|LARBIN-EXPERIMENTAL \(efp@gmx\.net\)|LetsCrawl\.com/1\.0 \+http\://letscrawl\.com/|Lincoln State Web Browser|LMQueueBot/0\.2|LWP\:\:Simple/5\.803|Mac Finder 1\.0\.xx|MFC Foundation Class Library 4\.0|Microsoft URL Control - 6\.00\.8xxx|Missauga Locate 1\.0\.0|Missigua Locator 1\.9|Missouri College Browse|Mizzu Labs 2\.2|Mo College 1\.9|MVAClient|Mozilla/2\.0 \(compatible; NEWT ActiveX; Win32\)|Mozilla/3\.0 \(compatible; Indy Library\)|Mozilla/3\.0 \(compatible; scan4mail \(advanced version\) http\://www\.peterspages\.net/?scan4mail\)|Mozilla/4\.0 \(compatible; Advanced Email Extractor v2\.xx\)|Mozilla/4\.0 \(compatible; Iplexx Spider/1\.0 http\://www\.iplexx\.at\)|Mozilla/4\.0 \(compatible; MSIE 5\.0; Windows NT; DigExt; DTS Agent|Mozilla/4\.0 efp@gmx\.net|Mozilla/5\.0 \(Version\: xxxx Type\:xx\)|NameOfAgent \(CMS Spider\)|NASA Search 1\.0|Nsauditor/1\.x|PBrowse 1\.4b|PEval 1\.4b|Poirot|Port Huron Labs|Production Bot 0116B|Production Bot 2016B|Production Bot DOT 3016B|Program Shareware 1\.0\.2|PSurf15a 11|PSurf15a 51|PSurf15a VA|psycheclone|RSurf15a 41|RSurf15a 51|RSurf15a 81|searchbot admin@google\.com|ShablastBot 1\.0|snap\.com beta crawler v0|Snapbot/1\.0|Snapbot/1\.0 \(Snap Shots&#44; \+http\://www\.snap\.com\)|sogou develop spider|Sogou Orion spider/3\.0\(\+http\://www\.sogou\.com/docs/help/webmasters\.htm#07\)|sogou spider|Sogou web spider/3\.0\(\+http\://www\.sogou\.com/docs/help/webmasters\.htm#07\)|sohu agent|SSurf15a 11 |TSurf15a 11|Under the Rainbow 2\.2|User-Agent\: Mozilla/4\.0 \(compatible; MSIE 6\.0; Windows NT 5\.1\)|VadixBot|WebVulnCrawl\.unknown/1\.0 libwww-perl/5\.803|Wells Search II|WEP Search 00

failregex = (?i)^<HOST> -.*"(GET|POST|HEAD|PUT).*"(?:%(badbots)s|%(badbotscustom)s)"$

ignoreregex =
```

But, I looked at the line you coppied from your log and if the above does not work (you can test it by changing you user agent string in chrome's dev tools) and you might have to change the failregex to match your log 'structure' to:

```
failregex = (?i)^<HOST> -.*(GET|POST|HEAD|PUT).*".*".*"(?:%(badbots)s|%(badbotscustom)s)"$
```

Comment: Thanks! After several tries found that .* sepatators work.
now *failregex* string look like

`failregex = ^<HOST> .* (GET|POST|HEAD|PUT).*HTTP.*(%(badbots)s).*$`
and it work fine now.

Comment: Its a pleasure, can you please upvote my awnser (I got banned because noone upvotes my awnsers, Otherwise I will leave these sites)